# Non-copyrighted free to use template similar to the AIP template?

Tags: templates, copyright

https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/aip/

Is there a similar template to this which isn't copyrighted?

Comment: Interesting. I see no legal basis for sharelatex's distribution of that template - not even as part of the original zip rather than on its own. As far as I can tell, nobody has a right to use or distribute the AIP files from the original zip with the exception of the .bst files which are under the LPPL. They are all copyright and there is no licence. That means no rights to do anything with them. (I know you asked for an alternative - I just find it interesting that sharelatex apparently ignore the legalities. Otherwise, I'd expect the header to be modified or the README mentioned included.)

Comment: The template is from RevTeX with is under LPPL license, and it appears in TeX Live.

Comment: Copyright is jurisdiction-dependent but in many (most?) places exists automatically and may not be 'removable' (not all countries have a 'public domain' concept). Do you mean something about the license instead?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a legal-centred matter.